# Does SIP remain disabled upon a fresh restart?

Tags: macos

System Integrity Protection re-enables itself upon a new restart of the machine.
So whenever you want it to be disabled for whatever reason you have to go back to recovery-mode and disable it manually.
I don't know why it does this but it does, even though it shouldn't.
It should in any case, even after an extended period of time stay disabled, since that was that command i gave the machine.

Is there any way to override this matter?

Comment: What model of Mac, running what OS?

Comment: To be clear, this is not normal behavior! I assume by "a new restart of the machine", you mean when the machine is powered off and then turned back on again, as opposed to a "warm" reboot, right? I ask because you can't get out of recovery mode without a warm reboot. SIP status is stored in your Mac's nvram, so I would guess there's a hardware issue that's causing nvram to get cleared on power off.

Comment: I'm upvoting this; I was surprised to see it at -3! It's a fine question, it just needs some editing cleanup. If no one else beats me, I intend to put in a suggested edit once OP clarifies my question about warm reboots.